# Need p4python commands to sync code from Perforce

Tags: p4python

I'm writing a script to sync code from Perforce. I'm using P4Python. Im very new to this. i need P4Python commands for below.

1. How to find latest Changelist number of a directory in Perforce.
   e.g. Want to find latest CL of //cbuDepot/cpe/foo/...
2. How to sync the code from Perforce with latest CL    e.g. Want to sync latest code from //cbuDepot/cpe/foo/...
3. How to sync the code from Perforce to older CL(Not latest)

Answer (score 0):

Find latest changelist number of a directory:

```
p4.run("changes", "-s", "submitted", "-m", "1", "//cbuDepot/cpe/foo/..."  )
```

Sync to latest changelist:

```
p4.run("sync", "//cbuDepot/cpe/foo/...")
```

Sync to older changelist:

```
p4.run("sync", "//cbuDepot/cpe/foo/...@123")
```

To use a variable "changelist":

```
p4.run("sync", "//cbuDepot/cpe/foo/...@"+ changelist)
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for the reply. In third answer, how to specify variable? i want to sync to a older CL & CL number is in var1. tried below:                           p4.run("sync", "//cbuDepot/cpe/foo/...@var1"). it didnt work. kindly help me.

Comment: HI, Thanks a lot for the response. i need some more info.                       1)How to specify clientspec? e.g: i want to sync code at //cbuDepot/cpe/foo/... into my local machine at: D:/abc/foo/...                                                                                                    i did this.   p4.run_login()    client = p4.fetch_client(CLIENT).  Then,  to know, latest CL, i ran:   p4.run("changes", "-s", "submitted", "-m", "1", "//cbuDepot/cpe/foo/..."  ). it gave incorrect CL. it was giving CL latest check-in in complete P4 server.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: To specify a clientspec (aka workspace), add this line before running any commands:   p4.client = "MyClient"

Comment: @tkosinski Hi, I want to find latest changelist number using the Perforce plugin (P4) for jenkins. So In my jenkins pipeline (which is Pipeline script from SCM running in groovy sandbox), I do sync the perforce using p4.run("sync"). I want to get changelist number here. is there any way??